# Race conditions in NodeJS MySQL without connection pooling

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I'm using a NodeJS Express server to connect to a DigitalOcean MySQL Database - unfortunately, DigitalOcean managed databases do not support connection pooling.

I don't think I can have one connection open for a really long time - it times out eventually.

So I thought up two methods to keep my web app running without needing to restart it every few days.

```js
// On every single request
async function someRequestHandler () {
  await db.connect()
  
  await db.query('SOME QUERY')
  await db.query('SOME OTHER QUERY')
  
  await db.end()
}
```

or having a timer that reconnects after a little while has passed

```js
async function reconnect () {
  await db.connect()
  
  setTimeout(async () => {
    await db.end()
    reconnect()
  }, SOME_LARGE_TIMEOUT)
}

async function someRequestHandler () {
  await db.query('SOME QUERY')
  await db.query('SOME OTHER QUERY')
}
```

However, with my request handlers being async functions that `await` queries - sometimes multiple per request - and with the web app getting quite frequent requests - am I right in saying that there could be a race wherein the first query runs and, while it's being waited on, the reconnection timer could fire or a different request handler could mess with the connection in the case of either method?

How should I deal with an endless, reliable MySQL connection in a web app without race conditions?

Comment: Connection pooling may not be available, but multiple connections probably are available.

Comment: What do you mean "don't support connection pooling"? It's not a function of the database so much as the database library you use.

Comment: @tadman Yes, I thought similar, but they say https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/databases/mysql/#mysql-limits "Connection pooling is not supported for MySQL." and the mysql2 npm package throws if I try to call `mysql.createPool`

Comment: If you need to ensure it doesn't fire twice, have a condition variable that you can set to ensure it doesn't happen, then test for that condition being set before proceeding. It's not clear what `db.end()` will do here that causes "race conditions". Where is `db` coming from? Can it be an instance property like `this.db` you could simply reassign?

Comment: There's client-side and server-side connection pooling. They have disabled server-side, but this does not preclude client-side use.

Comment: Web apps typically do not require persistent database connections due to the request - response nature of http.